# Python pandas str.extract regex end of string

Tags: regex, pandas

```
data.Hotel_Address.head(10)

0     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
1     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
2     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
3     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
4     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
5     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
6     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
7     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
8     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
9     s Gravesandestraat 55 Oost 1092 AA Amsterdam ...
```

How can I extract country name after last space till the end of string with regex in pandas?

Comment: Yes. You can.
And if you want more details please tell us what have you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is not necessary, use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select last lists by `str[-1]`:

```
data['new'] = data.Hotel_Address.str.split().str[-1]
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.